# Python: use of isalnum() method in QString

Tags: python, qstring

I'm trying to check if the user's input is alphanumeric. I tried using isalnum but it always shows this error:

> AttributeError: 'QString' object has no attribute 'isalnum'

what would be the best way to know if a string is alphanumeric in QString?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting to str and then checking should work

```
str(QString).isalnum()
```